# How to create scaling effect for button in CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

I tried to create a button whose ::after gets scaled when clicked. I tried and tried but couldn't. I think this effect is possible via CSS only. So please help.
Please help me to create this button as of gif:

[image: Click to see]

Like:

```
#button::after:active{
   transform: scale(2);
}
```

or something like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:before` pseudo-element to create another rectangle under button and use `transform` to scale it on click. Instead of css `:active` state you can use `click` event. After you click on element you need to click on some other element to remove active state and see effect again on click.

```css
button {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 50px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
}
button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  z-index: -1;
}
button:focus:before {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Sir that's awesome but why does that blue outline appears when :before opacity gets 0?

Comment: i MEAN :before!

Comment: It doesn't anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<button class="scale-btn">Text</button>
```

CSS

```
    .scale-btn{
  padding:6px 12px;
  border:none;
  background-color: #212121;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}
.scale-btn::after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:auto;
  transform:scale(1);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  opacity:1;
  transition:all ease 0.5s;
  z-index:-1;
}
.scale-btn:hover::after{
  animation:grow 0.5s ease;
}

@keyframes grow
{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(1.2);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

Style accordingly

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/zwo3o0un/4/)

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need it with :after?

```css
.button {
  margin: 2em;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
```